# Understanding solr cloud debug information

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a solr cloud setup with 5 nodes, 5 shards and replicationFactor=2. As I understand when we query solr cloud, the request is sent to shard leader which then directs the request to the replica. So a query result must be fetched from a single replica. But when I query with debug info enabled I see that query request is being sent to all the replicas. Below is the attached debug info

```
  "debug":{
    "track":{
      "rid":"-collection_shard2_replica1-1521525496479-3",
      "EXECUTE_QUERY":{
        "http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard2_replica2/|http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard2_replica1/":{
          "QTime":"0",
          "ElapsedTime":"4",
          "RequestPurpose":"GET_TOP_IDS",
          "NumFound":"3882137",
          "Response":"{responseHeader={zkConnected=true,status=0,QTime=0,params={df=contents,f.contents.hl.fragsize=50,distrib=false,hl=false,f.ttl.hl.snippets=1,f.kw_skl.hl.simple.post=</span>,fl=[id, score],shards.purpose=4,fsv=true,f.kw_skl.hl.snippets=1,f.ttl.hl.fragsize=0,shard.url=http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard2_replica2/|http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard2_replica1/,rid=-collection_shard2_replica1-1521525496479-3,f.kw_skl.hl.fragsize=0,hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_it.hl.alternateField=kw_it,f.kw_skl.hl.alternateField=kw_skl,defType=edismax,f.ttl.hl.simple.post=</span>,qf=contents currdesig lng ttl kw_skl kw_it,hl.highlightAlternate=false,f.contents.hl.snippets=3,hl.fl=ttl,kw_skl,kw_it,contents,wt=javabin,_=1521525657029,debug=[false, timing, track],qt=/resumesearch,f.contents.hl.simple.post=</span>,start=0,f.kw_it.hl.fragsize=0,f.kw_it.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,rows=10,version=2,hl.encoder=html,f.kw_it.hl.snippets=1,f.ttl.hl.alternateField=ttl,q=*:*,f.ttl.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,hl.simple.post=</span>,requestPurpose=GET_TOP_IDS,NOW=1521525496479,isShard=true,hl.method=postings,f.contents.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_skl.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_it.hl.simple.post=</span>,debugQuery=false}},response={numFound=3882137,start=0,maxScore=1.0,docs=[SolrDocument{id=82569162, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=82569230, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=82569265, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=82569294, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=82569309, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=82569313, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=82569386, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=35263232, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=35263237, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=35263300, score=1.0}]},sort_values={},debug={timing={time=0.0,prepare={time=0.0,query={time=0.0},facet={time=0.0},facet_module={time=0.0},mlt={time=0.0},highlight={time=0.0},stats={time=0.0},expand={time=0.0},terms={time=0.0},debug={time=0.0}},process={time=0.0,query={time=0.0},facet={time=0.0},facet_module={time=0.0},mlt={time=0.0},highlight={time=0.0},stats={time=0.0},expand={time=0.0},terms={time=0.0},debug={time=0.0}}}}}"},
        "http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard3_replica2/|http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard3_replica1/":{
          "QTime":"0",
          "ElapsedTime":"5",
          "RequestPurpose":"GET_TOP_IDS",
          "NumFound":"3884681",
          "Response":"{responseHeader={zkConnected=true,status=0,QTime=0,params={df=contents,f.contents.hl.fragsize=50,distrib=false,hl=false,f.ttl.hl.snippets=1,f.kw_skl.hl.simple.post=</span>,fl=[id, score],shards.purpose=4,fsv=true,f.kw_skl.hl.snippets=1,f.ttl.hl.fragsize=0,shard.url=http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard3_replica2/|http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard3_replica1/,rid=-collection_shard2_replica1-1521525496479-3,f.kw_skl.hl.fragsize=0,hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_it.hl.alternateField=kw_it,f.kw_skl.hl.alternateField=kw_skl,defType=edismax,f.ttl.hl.simple.post=</span>,qf=contents currdesig lng ttl kw_skl kw_it,hl.highlightAlternate=false,f.contents.hl.snippets=3,hl.fl=ttl,kw_skl,kw_it,contents,wt=javabin,_=1521525657029,debug=[false, timing, track],qt=/resumesearch,f.contents.hl.simple.post=</span>,start=0,f.kw_it.hl.fragsize=0,f.kw_it.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,rows=10,version=2,hl.encoder=html,f.kw_it.hl.snippets=1,f.ttl.hl.alternateField=ttl,q=*:*,f.ttl.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,hl.simple.post=</span>,requestPurpose=GET_TOP_IDS,NOW=1521525496479,isShard=true,hl.method=postings,f.contents.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_skl.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_it.hl.simple.post=</span>,debugQuery=false}},response={numFound=3884681,start=0,maxScore=1.0,docs=[SolrDocument{id=55933756, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=72335162, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=72335169, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=72335184, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=55933816, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=55933834, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=55933978, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=55934020, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=55934028, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=55934052, score=1.0}]},sort_values={},debug={timing={time=0.0,prepare={time=0.0,query={time=0.0},facet={time=0.0},facet_module={time=0.0},mlt={time=0.0},highlight={time=0.0},stats={time=0.0},expand={time=0.0},terms={time=0.0},debug={time=0.0}},process={time=0.0,query={time=0.0},facet={time=0.0},facet_module={time=0.0},mlt={time=0.0},highlight={time=0.0},stats={time=0.0},expand={time=0.0},terms={time=0.0},debug={time=0.0}}}}}"},
        "http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard1_replica1/|http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard1_replica3/":{
          "QTime":"0",
          "ElapsedTime":"3",
          "RequestPurpose":"GET_TOP_IDS",
          "NumFound":"3884574",
          "Response":"{responseHeader={zkConnected=true,status=0,QTime=0,params={df=contents,f.contents.hl.fragsize=50,distrib=false,hl=false,f.ttl.hl.snippets=1,f.kw_skl.hl.simple.post=</span>,fl=[id, score],shards.purpose=4,fsv=true,f.kw_skl.hl.snippets=1,f.ttl.hl.fragsize=0,shard.url=http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard1_replica1/|http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard1_replica3/,rid=-collection_shard2_replica1-1521525496479-3,f.kw_skl.hl.fragsize=0,hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_it.hl.alternateField=kw_it,f.kw_skl.hl.alternateField=kw_skl,defType=edismax,f.ttl.hl.simple.post=</span>,qf=contents currdesig lng ttl kw_skl kw_it,hl.highlightAlternate=false,f.contents.hl.snippets=3,hl.fl=ttl,kw_skl,kw_it,contents,wt=javabin,_=1521525657029,debug=[false, timing, track],qt=/resumesearch,f.contents.hl.simple.post=</span>,start=0,f.kw_it.hl.fragsize=0,f.kw_it.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,rows=10,version=2,hl.encoder=html,f.kw_it.hl.snippets=1,f.ttl.hl.alternateField=ttl,q=*:*,f.ttl.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,hl.simple.post=</span>,requestPurpose=GET_TOP_IDS,NOW=1521525496479,isShard=true,hl.method=postings,f.contents.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_skl.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_it.hl.simple.post=</span>,debugQuery=false}},response={numFound=3884574,start=0,maxScore=1.0,docs=[SolrDocument{id=30504181, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=30504213, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=30504221, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=30504252, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=30504264, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=30504291, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=30504319, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=30504346, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=30504350, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=30504355, score=1.0}]},sort_values={},debug={timing={time=0.0,prepare={time=0.0,query={time=0.0},facet={time=0.0},facet_module={time=0.0},mlt={time=0.0},highlight={time=0.0},stats={time=0.0},expand={time=0.0},terms={time=0.0},debug={time=0.0}},process={time=0.0,query={time=0.0},facet={time=0.0},facet_module={time=0.0},mlt={time=0.0},highlight={time=0.0},stats={time=0.0},expand={time=0.0},terms={time=0.0},debug={time=0.0}}}}}"},
        "http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard4_replica1/|http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard4_replica3/":{
          "QTime":"2",
          "ElapsedTime":"6",
          "RequestPurpose":"GET_TOP_IDS",
          "NumFound":"3881377",
          "Response":"{responseHeader={zkConnected=true,status=0,QTime=2,params={df=contents,f.contents.hl.fragsize=50,distrib=false,hl=false,f.ttl.hl.snippets=1,f.kw_skl.hl.simple.post=</span>,fl=[id, score],shards.purpose=4,fsv=true,f.kw_skl.hl.snippets=1,f.ttl.hl.fragsize=0,shard.url=http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard4_replica1/|http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard4_replica3/,rid=-collection_shard2_replica1-1521525496479-3,f.kw_skl.hl.fragsize=0,hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_it.hl.alternateField=kw_it,f.kw_skl.hl.alternateField=kw_skl,defType=edismax,f.ttl.hl.simple.post=</span>,qf=contents currdesig lng ttl kw_skl kw_it,hl.highlightAlternate=false,f.contents.hl.snippets=3,hl.fl=ttl,kw_skl,kw_it,contents,wt=javabin,_=1521525657029,debug=[false, timing, track],qt=/resumesearch,f.contents.hl.simple.post=</span>,start=0,f.kw_it.hl.fragsize=0,f.kw_it.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,rows=10,version=2,hl.encoder=html,f.kw_it.hl.snippets=1,f.ttl.hl.alternateField=ttl,q=*:*,f.ttl.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,hl.simple.post=</span>,requestPurpose=GET_TOP_IDS,NOW=1521525496479,isShard=true,hl.method=postings,f.contents.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_skl.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_it.hl.simple.post=</span>,debugQuery=false}},response={numFound=3881377,start=0,maxScore=1.0,docs=[SolrDocument{id=83997361, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=86755299, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=83997456, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=83997474, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=83997636, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=83997702, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=83997734, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=83997739, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=83997740, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=33944905, score=1.0}]},sort_values={},debug={timing={time=2.0,prepare={time=1.0,query={time=1.0},facet={time=0.0},facet_module={time=0.0},mlt={time=0.0},highlight={time=0.0},stats={time=0.0},expand={time=0.0},terms={time=0.0},debug={time=0.0}},process={time=0.0,query={time=0.0},facet={time=0.0},facet_module={time=0.0},mlt={time=0.0},highlight={time=0.0},stats={time=0.0},expand={time=0.0},terms={time=0.0},debug={time=0.0}}}}}"},
        "http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard5_replica2/|http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard5_replica1/":{
          "QTime":"1",
          "ElapsedTime":"5",
          "RequestPurpose":"GET_TOP_IDS",
          "NumFound":"3885899",
          "Response":"{responseHeader={zkConnected=true,status=0,QTime=1,params={df=contents,f.contents.hl.fragsize=50,distrib=false,hl=false,f.ttl.hl.snippets=1,f.kw_skl.hl.simple.post=</span>,fl=[id, score],shards.purpose=4,fsv=true,f.kw_skl.hl.snippets=1,f.ttl.hl.fragsize=0,shard.url=http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard5_replica2/|http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard5_replica1/,rid=-collection_shard2_replica1-1521525496479-3,f.kw_skl.hl.fragsize=0,hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_it.hl.alternateField=kw_it,f.kw_skl.hl.alternateField=kw_skl,defType=edismax,f.ttl.hl.simple.post=</span>,qf=contents currdesig lng ttl kw_skl kw_it,hl.highlightAlternate=false,f.contents.hl.snippets=3,hl.fl=ttl,kw_skl,kw_it,contents,wt=javabin,_=1521525657029,debug=[false, timing, track],qt=/resumesearch,f.contents.hl.simple.post=</span>,start=0,f.kw_it.hl.fragsize=0,f.kw_it.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,rows=10,version=2,hl.encoder=html,f.kw_it.hl.snippets=1,f.ttl.hl.alternateField=ttl,q=*:*,f.ttl.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,hl.simple.post=</span>,requestPurpose=GET_TOP_IDS,NOW=1521525496479,isShard=true,hl.method=postings,f.contents.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_skl.hl.simple.pre= <span class=\"bg_yellow\">,f.kw_it.hl.simple.post=</span>,debugQuery=false}},response={numFound=3885899,start=0,maxScore=1.0,docs=[SolrDocument{id=38604136, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=38604159, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=38604197, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=38604210, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=38604216, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=38604237, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=38604252, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=38604258, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=38604260, score=1.0}, SolrDocument{id=38604290, score=1.0}]},sort_values={},debug={timing={time=1.0,prepare={time=0.0,query={time=0.0},facet={time=0.0},facet_module={time=0.0},mlt={time=0.0},highlight={time=0.0},stats={time=0.0},expand={time=0.0},terms={time=0.0},debug={time=0.0}},process={time=0.0,query={time=0.0},facet={time=0.0},facet_module={time=0.0},mlt={time=0.0},highlight={time=0.0},stats={time=0.0},expand={time=0.0},terms={time=0.0},debug={time=0.0}}}}}"}},
      "GET_FIELDS":{
        "http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard2_replica2/|http://ip:8983/solr/collection_shard2_replica1/":{
          "QTime":"27",
          "ElapsedTime":"31",
          "RequestPurpose":"GET_FIELDS,GET_HIGHLIGHTS,GET_DEBUG",
          "NumFound":"10",
```

As it can be seen in "EXECUTE_QUERY" section, the request is being sent to all replicas. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

The first phase of your query is to find out which shards have documents that meet your criteria, and which documents those are. Since there's no *centralized* way to determine which shards hold documents that meet your criteria, the query is sent to *all* shards in parallel via a GET_TOP_IDS request. The GET_TOP_IDS is sent to either the primary *or* replica for a given shard...not both.

From there, the GET_DATA_FIELDS will be sent to one or more shards depending on sort/rows/score to get the requested data from a subset of documents identified by GET_TOP_IDS

Comment: How does a node determine which node(s) in the other shard(s) to query using GET_TOP_IDS?